# Is it possible to enumerate the AppDomains in a remote process?

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388554/list-appdomains-in-process) and a number of blog posts related to using `mscoree.CorRuntimeHostClass.EnumDomains` method to enumerate the AppDomains within the *current* process, but I'm wondering if there's a way to enumerate the AppDomains within a separate process on the same machine.

I'd like to be able to write a simple console or even WinForms app that could take a process ID and be able to give me some information about the AppDomains within that process. Is this even possible? I assume it is to some degree given that Process Explorer can give you a list of the AppDomains for a .NET process. I just want to know how to accomplish this with C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you would need to use the debugging API to do it.  This is broadly similar to the post you link to, but you use different APIs and interfaces.  See [Publishing Processes in the Debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384598.aspx) for an overview and links.

In particular, see the CorpubPublish coclass and the ICorPublish interface, then track down through ICorPublish::GetProcess and ICorPublishProcess::EnumAppDomains.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this [post 'Enumerating Managed Processes'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2004/11/25/270182.aspx) by Mike Stall should solve the problem.