# How to call crossappdomaindelegate-Method with parameters

Tags: c#, appdomain

i would like to call the method crossappdomaindelegate with a method-name which needs a parameter.

Example:

```
myAppdomain.DoCallback(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(MyMethod));

private static void MyMethod(string myParam)
{
  Console.Write("my param="+ myParam);
}
```

how can I pass a parameter in new CrossAppDomainDelegate(MyMethod....)?

**Update:** 
Just to complete Maarten's answer to my specific case:
I had also add an ResolveHandler to find already loaded assemblies.
Just if anyone else has similar Problems.

```
_myNewAppDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolveEventHandler;

        public static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            var dllName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];

            var currentAppdomain = (AppDomain) sender;

            var file = currentAppdomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(f => f.FullName.Split(',')[0] == dllName);

            return file;
        }
```

Comment: You can't do that directly - the delegate doesn't provide any parameters. Personally I usually use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) and call an instance-method directly in the other `AppDomain`. Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242573/simplest-way-to-make-cross-appdomain-call)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm also using CreateInstanceAndUnwrap but before I have to find out the exact Class-Name of the assembly --> i have to load the assembly first (in other appdomain) to find out what types are in there -->have do load them via DoCallback. Or are there better ways to find out the class-name of the assembly? maybe you can share some code? I only know they implement one of my three interfaces. best Regards

Comment: I've added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to retrieve the types in an assembly in another `AppDomain`.

First, define some dummy classes:

```
public class X1 { }
public class X2 { }
public class X3 { }
public class X4 { }
public class X5 { }
```

Then define a specific class to load the types from an assembly:

```
public class TypesProvider : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public string[] RetrieveTypes()
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
    }

    public string[] RetrieveTypesForAnotherAssembly(string assemblyFile)
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFile).GetTypes().Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And use that class to retrieve the types from an assembly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("type-provider-appdomain");
        var typeProviderInstance = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(TypesProvider).Assembly.FullName, typeof(TypesProvider).FullName) as TypesProvider;
        if (typeProviderInstance != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Types for the executing assembly");
            var types = typeProviderInstance.RetrieveTypes();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type);
            }
            var assemblyFile = new FileInfo("EntityFramework.dll").FullName;
            Console.WriteLine("Types for assembly " + assemblyFile);
            types = typeProviderInstance.RetrieveTypesForAnotherAssembly(assemblyFile);
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The first usage of the TypesProvider will yield the dummy classes

```
Types for the executing assembly
SO_3543881.Program
SO_3543881.TypesProvider
SO_3543881.X1
SO_3543881.X2
SO_3543881.X3
SO_3543881.X4
SO_3543881.X5
```

The second call will yield all types from the EntityFramework assembly (if you have placed it in the bin folder).

Comment: thank you Maarten. I also had a "Proxy"-class like your TypeProvider but always made the mistake to return the assembly instead of only the types which was always leading to missing dependencies. Changing my Code to your Suggestion saved me :) thanks a lot!!