# How to get AppDomain by name?

Tags: .net, clr

Is it possible to get reference to an existing AppDomain (created not by mine code) by it's "friendly name" or id? Or in any other way?

Comment: Dont think this is possible due to security concerns. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[List AppDomains in Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388554/list-appdomains-in-process)