# Find the appdomain for a MarshalByRef object

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a marshalled object which originated in another app domain.

**Is there a way to get a reference to the app domain where the object was created from the object itself?**

```
//i dont have a ref to this anymore.
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
MyRemoteObject r = (MyRemoteObject)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("MyCode.dll", "MyRemoteObject");

//is there a something such that i can re-discover the app domain
var appDomain = Something(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer of [How to Get an AppDomain from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803706/get-the-appdomain-of-object)

One possibility would be to create a property on your remote object.  The remote object could then call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` to get the remote AppDomain.

Comment: I had a look at that post but the answer is really talking about serialised objects not marshalled objects. Unfortunately I don't control the object at the other end of the app domain so I cant really just do an `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` in the remote domain.

Comment: @IllidanS4 it doesn't look like its been updated, it still requires actions from the remote object.