# How many AppDomains are running in application?

Tags: .net, clr, appdomain

If I start console, wpf or asp.net application, will .Net create any AppDomain? Could I assume that there is always exactly one AppDomain?

Comment: How to count AppDomains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/388582/600559

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is always one, unless you, or any third party library you use, creates new `AppDomain`s.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) an `AppDomain` is an

> isolated environment where applications execute

This might be useful when your software loads some untrusted assemblies as add-ins for example. You could create a secundary `AppDomain`, load the untrusted assemblies in there, and execute their methods, without having the risk it tempers your original `AppDomain`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for a console mode app and a WPF app.  It is murkier for an ASP.NET app, it uses appdomains to isolate web sites.  And a web site can migrate from one to another when it shadow-copies assemblies.