# How to tell the number of Application Domains created in a .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .Net (C#) process and I want to be able to tell the number of AppDomains that have been created.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to check this programatically? During runtime you can use ProcessExplorer to check the AppDomains of an .NET process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, and it probably doesn't make sense.
How are these AppDomains being created? If you have control over this, you can add a counter, or add them to a global collection.

Comment: I stand corrected: it is possible, according to the explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388554/list-appdomains-in-process

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you are investigating something.

You might use a 3rd party memory profiler to check how many instances of AppDomain you have.

It's a big tool for the question you are asking, but it does the trick.

ANTS memory profiler by Red Gate i recommend, i've used it. It shows you the number of instances per Type, and its an amazing tool if you're investigating into some kind of memory leak.