# How to check if AppDomain is unloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I'm using a bunch of objects in another AppDomain through proxy. They are in a separate domain because I need to hot-swap assemblies that contain those objects, so I Unload an AppDomain after I'm done using the assemblies it's hosting.

I want to check sometimes if I've unloaded an AppDomain in the past (or it somehow got unloaded on its own or something) for testing purposes. Is there a way to do this?

The obvious way is to do something that would throw an `AppDomainUnloadedException`, but I'm hoping there is some other way.

Comment: Some programmers try entirely too hard to avoid using a *bool* variable.  There is no "or something".

Comment: @HansPassant Since it's for testing purposes there is usually an *or something*, even if you're adamantly certain there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can use a combination of storing references of `AppDomain` in some given `Dictionary<AppDomain, bool>` where the `bool` is if its loaded or unloaded, and handle `AppDomain.DomainUnload` event.

```
Dictionary<AppDomain, bool> appDomainState = new Dictionary<AppDomain, bool>();

AppDomain appDomain = ...; // AppDomain creation
appDomain.DomainUnload += (sender, e) => appDomainState[appDomain] = false;
appDomainState.Add(appDomain, true);
```

This way you'll be able to check if an `AppDomain` is unloaded:

```
// "false" is "unloaded"
if(!appDomainState[appDomainReference]) 
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `AppDomain.Id` as key:

```
Dictionary<int, bool> appDomainState = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

AppDomain appDomain = ...; // AppDomain creation
appDomain.DomainUnload += (sender, e) => appDomainState[appDomain.Id] = false;
appDomainState.Add(appDomain.Id, true);
```

...and the if statement would look as follows:

```
// "false" is "unloaded"
if(!appDomainState[someAppDomainId]) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will do this if there is no direct way to check if the domain has been unloaded (since it's for testing purposes, the fewer failure points, the better).

Comment: @GregRos No problem. If I'm not mistaken, this will be your best bet. Obviously, you might change how you store the `AppDomain` state: it can be a dictionary as I suggested you, a list of classes using a custom type `AppDomainState` which might have a property `Unloaded`...

Answer (score 1):

You can list all appdomains in your program with the code from this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388554/list-appdomains-in-process). Then you can compare them by `ID` or `FriendlyName` or something similar.