# Avoid giving namespace name in Type.GetType()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, types

```
Type.GetType("TheClass");
```

Returns `null` if the `namespace` is not present like:

```
Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.TheClass"); // returns a Type object
```

Is there any way to avoid giving the `namespace` name?

Comment: do you realize that you could have multiple different classes called TheClass in a project where many references have been added and the file where you try to resolve the type has many using statements? You should pass the fully qualified name including namespace like when you reference yourself in a document you write First name and Last name. Which of many TheClass classes should the compiler use in case of many present? Namespace tells which one.

Comment: I would throw `ArgumentException` instead of just return `null`. You can't distinguish without `Namespace`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a System.Type from type's partial name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179102/getting-a-system-type-from-types-partial-name)

Answer (score 58):

I've used a helper method that searches all loaded [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx)s for a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) matching the specified name. Even though in my code only one Type result was expected it supports multiple. I verify that only one result is returned every time I used it and suggest you do the same.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a all Type instances matching the specified class name with just non-namespace qualified class name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="className">Name of the class sought.</param>
/// <returns>Types that have the class name specified. They may not be in the same namespace.</returns>
public static Type[] getTypeByName(string className)
{
    List<Type> returnVal = new List<Type>();

    foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        Type[] assemblyTypes = a.GetTypes();
        for (int j = 0; j < assemblyTypes.Length; j++)
        {
            if (assemblyTypes[j].Name == className)
            {
                returnVal.Add(assemblyTypes[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return returnVal.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question instead of piling on the flame war above.

Comment: another answer that is from someone who knows instead of dont use no namespace bla bla :) ty for answer

Comment: fantastic, does what it says.  The main thing I would add to this would be to use assemblyTypes[j].Name.EqualsIgnoreCase(className).

Answer (score 24):

There is no need to complicate things.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "MyTypeName");
```

Use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault` to get all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Cached version

Do this once....

```
        nameTypeLookup = typeof(AnyTypeWithin_SomeNamespace).Assembly
            .DefinedTypes.Where(t => t.DeclaringType == null)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v);
```

Usage - lookup many times via dictionary

```
nameTypeLookup["TheClass"];
```

Comment: This is elegant and reusable, and met my usage needs best compared to other answers (which also would've worked). Not sure why you got downvotes, because this a) works and b) is elegant / simple / concise if you want to load Types by their short name rather than the rather lengthy AssemblyQualifiedName, and you want to scope within your own specific assembly by anchoring to a known type that won't go away, such as the main table/entity in your ORM/EM.

Comment: Additionally, in my implementation of your answer, I can just say `this.GetType().Assembly...` without grabbing some other type, as my class that refers to other classes by short name is in the same assembly as the target classes.

`return this.GetType().Assembly.DefinedTypes.First(t => t.Name == ClassName);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers posted here, I use this in my extension static class :

```
public static readonly IEnumerable<Type> cachedAssembliesTypes =
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
         .GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes());

public static IEnumerable<Type>? GetTypesByName(this string typeName)
{
    Type? resultType = null;
    try
    {
        resultType = Type.GetType(typeName);
        if (resultType != null)
            return new Type[] { resultType };
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    string parameterTypeName = null;
    if (typeName.Contains('`') && typeName.Contains('['))
    { 
        parameterTypeName = typeName[typeName.IndexOf("[")..];
        typeName = typeName[..typeName.IndexOf("[")];
    }

    var result = CachedAssembliesTypes.Where(type => type.Name == typeName);
    if(parameterTypeName != null)
        result = result.Select(type => Type.GetType($"{type.Namespace}.{typeName}{parameterTypeName}"));

    return result;
}

public static Type? GetTypeByName(this string typeName)
    => GetTypesByName(typeName)?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -6):

That's the parameter the method expect to get, so no. You can not.

> typeName:  type name qualified by its namespace.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

How do you expect to distinguish between two classes with the same name but different Namespace?

```
namespace one
{
    public class TheClass
    {
    }
}

namespace two
{
    public class TheClass
    {
    }
}

Type.GetType("TheClass") // Which?!
```

Comment: According to my need there is no situation like this.

Comment: According to my need there will not be any situation like this.So in that case how can i go about it?

Comment: @NIleshLanke, I hope you realize that Microsoft didn't design the .NET framework according to **your** needs but it was architected to be used in a much more broader scenarios. Like for example a scenario where you have the same class name in two different namespaces.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov. +1. Though it could return that type if it finds that there is only one type in the assembly.

Comment: @NIleshLanke. Are you still having difficulties?

Comment: @gdoron, why the insistence in this post that it can't be don't when the accepted answer is showing that it can be?

Comment: @abc, "Avoid giving namespace name in Type.GetType()" that's the answer, if you want to use `Type.GetType` you have to pass the namespace.

Comment: @gdoron, No, you don't. The answer above literally shows you how to do it.

Comment: @gdoron, Even though the correct answer might be bad practice, it can still be done.

Comment: @Bracher, no, he didn't ask how he can get the Type of class without a namespace, he asked _"Avoid giving namespace name in Type.GetType()"_, and the answer is **you can NOT**. You can implement something else, but it won't bloody be `Type.GetType()`.

Comment: @gdoron, You need to look at what the user is actually after and not just the literal meaning of the question title. 

Its like me asking if I can drink a watermelon and you just replying "you can NOT", but then Fr33dan comes along and says "You can if you dice it up and throw it in a Nutribullet" - which is what I'm actually after. 

I think it is safe to say the user in this case just wanted some way to get the type without having to specify the namespace.

Comment: @gdoron, read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer especially the section regarding "Answer the question"