# How can I get a type(type object) with its friendly name(string)?

Tags: c#

For example, I want to have a method to get `typeof(int)` from `"int"`, `typeof(List<int>)` from `"List<int>"`, `typeof(Dictionary<string, int>)` from `"Dictionary<string,int>"`, etc.

If the friendly name is an ambiguous one in the calling context, it's ok to throw an exception or simply return a null.

I can use a dictionary to store the map for all built-in friendly types, but it would be too complicated to map every concrete generic type manually. I cannot find a way to build up all the friendly names I may need.

Is there some "eval" method in C# like in some script languages? I.e. so I can simply run `typeof` with the friendly name as input and get a `Type` object reference as the return value?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use CSharpCodeDomProvider (or related) to do this. Roslyn APIs as well

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `Type.GetType` eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetType_System_String_ - in combination with avoiding the namespace eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273629/avoid-giving-namespace-name-in-type-gettype - which instead of in `Type.GetType("System.Int32");` could give you `Type.GetTypeWithoutNamespace("Int32");`

Comment: I don't think the post about avoiding namespace works for generic types. I believe the GetTypes method of an assembly does not return a concrete version of a generic type, which means I have to make the concrete types manually using every generic parameter I want to support. Tell me if I am mistaken.

Comment: The `typeof` keyword works only at compile time. To obtain a `Type` object dynamically at runtime, you need reflection. See duplicates for solutions to both the non-generic and generic scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **.GetType().Name** to get type of an object in simple.

```
T.GetType().Name // class name, no namespace
T.GetType().FullName // namespace and class name
T.GetType().Namespace // namespace, no class name
```

Comment: GetType requires the fully qualified name of a type, which cannot be obtained from the user input, and it's somehow complicated to build up one manually.

Comment: You can also use typeof(T) as the sample => typeof(T).Name // class name, no namespace
typeof(T).FullName // namespace and class name
typeof(T).Namespace // namespace, no class name

Comment: It seems to me you've misunderstood the question. All three of your example statements assume that you already have something from which you can obtain a `Type` object. The question is asking _how to obtain that `Type` object in the first place_.