# Getting Class object from its string name in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using C# for developing mobile applications(Monotouch, monodroid).
I have a class by this definition:

```
public class TempIOAddOn : BaseIOAddOn 
{
    public TempIOAddOn ()
    {
    }
}
```

And I use this code to access an instance of class by its string name:

```
BaseIOAddOn tempIOAddOn;
            Type t= Type.GetType("TempIOAddOn" );
            tempIOAddOn  = (BaseIOAddOn)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

But after executation, `t` is `null`.

I tried below code also:

```
BaseIOAddOn tempIOAddOn;
            tempIOAddOn = (BaseIOAddOn )System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("TempIOAddOn" );
```

But again I face with `null`. `tempIOAddOn` is `null`.

What is wrong with me?

Comment: Try using the [Assembly Qualified Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) instead. If it's running Xamarin, it _might_ need to full qualified name. I've had the same limitations with Silverlight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a System.Type from a type's partial name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179102/getting-a-system-type-from-types-partial-name) **and** [type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [Assembly Qualified Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) instead. If it's running Xamarin, it *might* need to use the full qualified name. I've had the same limitations with Silverlight.

To quickly get the full name, just reference the type and output it:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(TempIOAddon).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

EDIT: Here's the MSDN doc for `Type.GetType(string)` for Silverlight. Since Xamarin's mobile platform is more or less based off it, generally the docs can apply: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Note that likely if the type is in the currently executing assembly, you'll probably only need the full namespace.name

Answer (score 8):

Your class is almost certainly included in a namespace. In this case you need to qualify the name of the type with its namespace:

```
Type t= Type.GetType("MyNamespace.TempIOAddOn");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. both answer is correct and just can choose one as answer. Instead 1 upvote for clear answer.