# Dynamically gets the properties of the class name

Tags: c#, console

I do have 10 to 15 classes and having its properties in it like ID, firstname and lastname etc...

Now I want to get the properties from class1 by giving class1 name and properties from class2 by giving class2 and so on dynamically.

Note: Console Application

Eg:

```
class class1
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string Firstname { get; set; }
 public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

class class2
    {
     public string Gender { get; set; }
     public string Address{ get; set; }
     public string Type{ get; set; }
    }

public static void Main()
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter ClassName");
    Console.ReadLine();  
    //To Do          
 }
```

I have googled it but unable to get the exact answer.

Comment: google reflection in c#

Comment: Also, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179102/getting-a-system-type-from-types-partial-name