# How to pass class name to DeserializeObject which i will get at runtime in string c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have to call below method which has 2 parameter

```
public static byte[] readdata(string classtype, string msg)
{
    Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    string header = $"{classtype},{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";

    byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

    var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<classtype>(msg);
```

> i want to pass classtype to method DeserializeObject which i will get at runtime.

but parameter is generic i may get `ClassA or ClassB or ClassC` so how can i call method and pass generic class name which i'm getting it into string value?

```
readdata("ClassA" , "testmessage");
```

Comment: You used the generic tag so why not a generic rather than passing a string?

Comment: when the type `ClassA` is in scope of `readdata`, then it may be in scope of callers of `readdata` too, so why not pass the type instead of a string? If it must be a string, you can use `nameof(ClassA)`. To obtain a type from a string, look into reflection, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179102/1132334)

Comment: Then according to your last comment it is a possible duplicate of [Getting a System.Type from type's partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179102/getting-a-system-type-from-types-partial-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying but should not this work:

```
readdata(nameof(ClassA), "");
readdata(nameof(ClassB), "");
...
```

You could use the following overload [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm)

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(msg, Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.ClassA"));
```

Assuming you are passing generic type parameters - here is what you can try:

```
public static void readdata(string classtype, string msg)
{
    ///... your stuff
}

static void SendType<T>()
{
    readdata(typeof(T).Name, "");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SendType<ClassA>();
    SendType<ClassB>();
    SendType<ClassC>();
}
```

But i am not sure if the above will still solve your problem, you should try:

```
public static byte[] readdata<T>(string msg)
{
    //Your code
    var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(msg);
}
```

Calling statement:

```
readdata<ClassA>("Some message");
readdata<ClassB>("Some message");
readdata<ClassC>("Some message");
```

Suggest to read the following [Type.GetType(“namespace.a.b.ClassName”) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Comment: i cannot do like this readdata<ClassA>("Some message"); because at runtime i'm getting value of class name.

Comment: Type.GetType works for me but it need `namespace.qualified.classname` full is there any other way to do it without a full specified?

Comment: @Neo - can you go to an Address if you only have the name of a city? I think you are doing something wrong.